# os.urandom (n) set n value to bits rather than bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do i input bits rather than bytes in os.urandom(n) function? I want to set the n value to 66 bits that is 8.25 bytes and floating numbers are not supported in it? or is there any other function that help me set the value of n to 66 bits?

```
import time
import datetime as dt
import smtplib
import os
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool
import binascii, hashlib, base58, ecdsa
import pandas as pd


def ripemd160(x):
    d = hashlib.new('ripemd160')
    d.update(x)
    return d


r = 0
cores=6


def seek(r, df_handler):
    global num_threads
    LOG_EVERY_N = 1000
    start_time = dt.datetime.today().timestamp()
    i = 0
    print("Core " + str(r) +":  Searching Private Key..")
    while True:
        i=i+1
        # generate private key , uncompressed WIF starts with "5"
        priv_key = os.urandom(32)
        fullkey = '80' + binascii.hexlify(priv_key).decode()
        sha256a = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(fullkey)).hexdigest()
        sha256b = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(sha256a)).hexdigest()
        WIF = base58.b58encode(binascii.unhexlify(fullkey+sha256b[:8]))

        # get public key , uncompressed address starts with "1"
        sk = ecdsa.SigningKey.from_string(priv_key, curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
        vk = sk.get_verifying_key()
        publ_key = '04' + binascii.hexlify(vk.to_string()).decode()
        hash160 = ripemd160(hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(publ_key)).digest()).digest()
        publ_addr_a = b"\x00" + hash160
        checksum = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(publ_addr_a).digest()).digest()[:4]
        publ_addr_b = base58.b58encode(publ_addr_a + checksum)
        priv = WIF.decode()
        pub = publ_addr_b.decode()
        time_diff = dt.datetime.today().timestamp() - start_time
        if (i % LOG_EVERY_N) == 0:
            print('Core :'+str(r)+" K/s = "+ str(i / time_diff))
        #print ('Worker '+str(r)+':'+ str(i) + '.-  # '+pub + ' # -------- # '+ priv+' # ')
        pub = pub + '\n'
        filename = 'bit.txt'
        with open(filename) as f:
            for line in f:
                if pub in line:
                    msg = "\nPublic: 
" + str(pub) + " ---- Private: " + str(priv) + "YEI"
                    text = msg
                    #UNCOMMENT IF 2FA from gmail is activated, or risk missing your winning ticket;)
                    #server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
                    #server.ehlo()
                    #server.starttls()
                    #server.login("example@gmail.com", "password")
                    #fromaddr = "example@gmail.com"
                    #toaddr = "example@gmail.com"
                    #server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
                    print(text)
                    with open('Wallets.txt','a') as f:
                        f.write(priv)
                        f.write('     ')
                        f.write(pub)
                        f.write('\n')
                        f.close()
                    time.sleep(30)
                    print ('WINNER WINNER CHICKEN DINNER!!! ---- ' +dt.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), pub, priv)
                    break
                    



contador=0
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    df_handler = pd.read_csv(open('bit.txt', 'r'))
    for r in range(cores):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=seek, args=(r,df_handler))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

this is the code and i want the os.urandom(32) to be 8.25 bytes (66 bit)

Comment: No, you can't ask `urandom` for fractional bytes. What is it that you actually need in the end? Do you need a 66-length list of 1s and 0s?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an integer with 66 random bits using the same random source as `os.urandom()` uses,

```
>>> import random
>>> x = random.SystemRandom().getrandbits(66)
46111822109486537585
```

If you want that integer as a "binary string" of length 66,

```
>>> bin(x)[2:].rjust(66, '0')
'100111111111101110000110011110010111001101111100101101101101110001'
```

(`bin()`'s output has a `0b` prefix, so we slice that off. In case any of the high-order bits are zero, they wouldn't be in the `bin()` output, so we pad the string to the desired length with zeroes.)

Comment: Minor improvement: Rather than `bin`-ing just to strip off the `0b` prefix, then right justify it, just do `'{:066b}'.format(x)` (or `format(x, '066b')` if you prefer) which formats it onto a `0` padded 66 wide field without the prefix directly. Not necessarily faster (in fact, testing shows it's slightly slower for this size), but more direct, and presumably involves less allocator churn.